# Bulk insert in MongoDB using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bulkinsert

I currently have a collection in Mongodb say "Collection1".
I have the following array of objects that need to be into inserted into MongoDB. I am using Mongoose API. For now, I am iterating through the array and inserting each of them into mongo.
This is ok for now, but will be a problem when the data is too big.
I need a way of inserting the data in bulk into MongoDB without repetition.
I am not sure how to do this. I could not find a bulk option in Mongoose.

My code below

```
myData = [Obj1,Obj2,Obj3.......]

myData.forEach(function(ele){
      //console.log(ele)
     saveToMongo(ele);
    });
function saveToMongo(obj){
    (new Collection1(obj)).save(function (err, response) {
          if (err) {
             // console.log('Error while inserting: ' + obj.name + " " +err);
          } else {
            // console.log('Data successfully inserted');
          }
      });

      return Collection1(obj);
  }
```

Answer (score 38):

You might want to use the **[`insertMany()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany)** method here if you're using the latest Mongoose version `4.4.X` and greater, which essentially uses **[`Model.collection.insertMany()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#insertMany)** under the hood and the driver might handle parallelizing `>= 1000` docs for you.

```
myData = [Obj1, Obj2, Obj3.......];
Collection1.insertMany(myData, function(error, docs) {});
```

or using Promises for better error handling

```
Collection1.insertMany(myData)
    .then(function(docs) {
         // do something with docs
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // error handling here
    });
```

It works by creating a bunch of documents, calls `.validate()` on them in parallel, and then calls the underlying driver's **[`insertMany()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#insertMany)** on the result of `toObject({ virtuals: false });` of each doc.
Although **[`insertMany()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany)** doesn't trigger pre-save hooks, it has better performance because it only makes 1 round-trip to the server rather than 1 for each document.

---

For Mongoose versions `~3.8.8, ~3.8.22, 4.x` which support MongoDB Server `>=2.6.x`, you could use the **[`Bulk API`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)** as follows

```
var bulk = Collection1.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0;

myData.forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.insert(doc);

    counter++;
    if (counter % 500 == 0) {
        bulk.execute(function(err, r) {
           // do something with the result
           bulk = Collection1.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
           counter = 0;
        });
    }
});

// Catch any docs in the queue under or over the 500's
if (counter > 0) {
    bulk.execute(function(err,result) {
       // do something with the result here
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying your way to add lot of data with `bulk` mongoose (I have 409 584 data to add) but I have just 273001 data added. Do you know why ?

Comment: What's your MongoDB server version?

Comment: I have MongoDB versio 3.2.9 and mongoose 4.7.2. If I use insertMany I got `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory` then I try to use bulk method.

Comment: can we preserve the order in which they created

Answer (score 3):

you can pass an array of objects to mongoose model create function

```
var Collection1 = mongoose.model('Collection1');

Collection1.create(myData,function(err){
    if(err) ...
});
```