# How to split an array json into separate records using mongoose in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a large array of object that I get from an API, this is its URL:
https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset_contracts/
I would like to take this JSON and pass it to MongoDB in a way that will create a record for each object in this array (currently there are ~230).

What will be the best way to do it? I currently have the json like so:

```
fetch("https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset_contrcts/"}).then(r => r.json())
.then(data => {
  // Add all of the data to a collection;
  return data;
});
```

}

What is the best way to do so? Run in a for loop over each of the objects and insert it or is there some way to do it in a more optimal way?

Comment: Use [insertMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) operation

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379180/bulk-insert-in-mongodb-using-mongoose/

Answer (score 0):

[db.collection.insertMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/)

this will solve your problem.
you need not  split the array json into separate records. just pass the array to inserMany() it will handled implicitly.